# Passing Parm from App.xaml to ViewModel - Silverlight MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a string UserName that resides in App.xaml.cs which I need to bring to a ViewModel to populate a control. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: How does it reside in App.xaml.cs?

Comment: I'm passing it as a <param> to Application_Startup. Which comes through as e.InitParams. I want to persist this user to the VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you most use control resource to access ViewModel instance.
then by a public method that defined in ViewModel you can pass parameters to it.

```
((ViewModel1)this.Resources["ViewModel1"]).Test(p);
```

Test is a public method in ViewModel that receive parameter.

Comment: This works thanks. However, I lose the value when my paired view instantiates the ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

You could send a message (e.g. MvvmLight Messenger class) containing the value, and the ViewModel would register to receive it.

In App.xaml.cs:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<string>(Username);
```

In the ViewModel's constructor:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, m => 
    {
        this.Username = m; // or whatever you need to do with the value
    });
```